# Rename files in folder vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have code to find a filename from column A and rename files as in column B in a source folder and then copy to a new folder.

The code is as below.

```
Sub Rename_Files()
    Dim SourcePath, DestPath, Fname, NewFName
    SourcePath = "C:\Invoices\"
    DestPath = "C:\Invoices\Renamed\"
    For i = 1 To 100
        Fname = Range("A" & i).Value
        NewFName = Range("B" & i).Value
        If Not Dir(SourcePath & Fname, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
            FileCopy SourcePath & Fname, DestPath & NewFName
        Else
            MsgBox (Fname & " Not Exists in Folder")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The problem is that The filenames in the source directory are long like `'INVOICEDUMP_OFND_4294819_ABC Corp.pdf'` and hundreds of like this.

I want to find the file containing 4294819 (from column A) in the name and then replace the name with only `'INV 4294819.pdf'` (as mentioned in column B).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless my DOS skills are extremely rusty, you should be able to use

```
Sub Rename_Files()
    Dim SourcePath As String, DestPath As String, Fname As String, NewFName As String
    Dim i As Long
    SourcePath = "C:\Invoices\"
    DestPath = "C:\Invoices\Renamed\"
    For i = 1 To 100
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i).Value) Then
            NewFName = Range("B" & i).Value
            'Search for the first file containing the string in column A
            Fname = Dir(SourcePath & "*" & Range("A" & i).Value & "*")
            If Fname <> vbNullString Then
                FileCopy SourcePath & Fname, DestPath & NewFName
            Else
                MsgBox Range("A" & i).Value & " Not Exists in Folder"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This assumes that column A has entries such as `4294819` and that the corresponding entry in column B is something like `INV 4294819.pdf`.